# Restore SVN ancestry of file copied and then edited

Tags: svn

I have a file in SVN that I copied a while back. The only problem is that I didn't do it with an `svn cp`, I did with with a normal `cp`. Now, I've made a bunch of edits to the file but it doesn't have any ancestry; the logs report it being added wholesale instead of being copied.

Is there a way for me to fix my SVN repository such that it contains both information about the copy and my edits?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to:

1. Save your file somewhere and delete it from repository
2. Perform the `svn cp` then checkout the file into your working copy
3. Overwrite the file with the one saved in step 1.
4. Commit it !